# convert string regex to regex with tag i

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

ok, I have a problem here, in my database I store regexPath that made from URL.
I used this package [path-to-regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regex)

so I store my converted path to regex as String in the database like this:

```
let path = "/v1/manager/notification/all"
let regexPath = "/^\/v1\/manager\/notification\/all(?:\/)?$/i"
```

and I need **test()** function for checking some condition.
ofcourse test() function need a regex format for checking value is exists in regex.the only way I found in internet for convert string to regex is :

```
let RegexPattern = new RegExp(regexPath)
```

but RegExp function consider my **i** tag as a part of regex him self and it returns something like this:

```
/"\/^\\\/v1\\\/manager\\\/notification\\\/all\\\/page\\=([^\\=\\\/]+?)(?:\\\/)?$\/i"/
```

how should I solve this problem?

Comment: capture and remove  the last values after after last `/`  before passing it to new RegExp, and pass captured values as flag, `new RegExp(pattern, flag)`

Comment: Could you store the regex options (the final "i" in your example) as another column in the database?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes I can , but I consider this now I can remove the tag before storing in database as code maniac mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the inner regex and flags before. Here's an example:

```js
const path = "/v1/manager/notification/all"
const regexPath = "/^\/v1\/manager\/notification\/all(?:\/)?$/i"

const separator = regexPath.lastIndexOf('/')

const pattern = regexPath.slice(1, separator)
const flags = regexPath.slice(separator + 1)

const regex = new RegExp(pattern, flags)

console.log('Pattern: ' + pattern)
console.log('Flags: ' + flags)
console.log('Regex: ' + regex)
```

Answer (score 1):

Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp you need to extract the modifiers yourself and pass them in as the second parameter. You will also need to remove the leading and trailing slashes.

```
new RegExp(pattern[, flags])
```